# Select Column Twice With Different Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables,Table 1 and Table 2, Table 1 has member_id,first name and last name,
Table 2 has buyer_id and seller_id I will like to select first name and last name of the buyer and seller in one row

```
    Table_1
   member id | firstname | lastname
    1        |  John     |  Richard
    2        | Joseph    |   Curly
    3        |  Ismail   |  Jake
    4        | Elijah    |   Michael

    Table_2
  seller_id  | buyer_id|
    2        |     1   |
    3        |     4   |
```

I have been trying to return a table with rows like this

```
 seller_id | buyer_id | firstname | lastname | firstname | lastname|
     2     |   1      |    Joseph |   Curly  |  John     | Richard |
```

The query i used is

```
SELECT a.firstname,a.lastname,a.firstname,a.lastname,b.seller_id,b.buyer_id
        FROM Table_1 as a,Table_2 as b WHERE b.buyer_id = a.member_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  join `table_1` twice (one for join `seller_id` and One for join  `buyer_id`)

```
SELECT 
    a.firstname
    ,a.lastname
    ,c.firstname
    ,c.lastname
    ,b.seller_id
    ,b.buyer_id
    FROM Table_2 as b
    INNER JOIN Table_1 as a ON a.member_id = b.seller_id
    INNER JOIN Table_1 as c On c.member_id = b.buyer_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will try this right away i do not really understand Table Joins

Comment: You need  an explanation or you have undestand  the answer ?

Comment: For Pete's sake. It's been 6 whole minutes, and you're begging for an accept? Give the poor guy a chance to read and understand the answer.

Comment: @ scaisEdge Please i will be greatful if you can explain.I just tried it and it worked perfectly.Thanks alot

Comment: The join allow to get information between related  tables  .. in this case you have two set of information coming from the same table  (table 2)  one are information for seller_id  and then you must join table 2 using seller_di  one is for buyer_id and the you must join table 2 via buyer_id  .. for retrive the correct information the table use in both the case is renamed using alias  a and c so SQL can acces to teh different set of info .. hope this is clear

Comment: Ok thanks.I will read more about Table Joins. can i replace b.buyer_id and b.seller_id with the values

Comment: yes you can replace the columns name with value but with columns name you a general query with value you join only the two values ..  .. the trick is that each time you create a table name alias  you have   a new table (also if is the same table) with all the same values of the original table